# SQL Where Clause with multiple and joined conditions

Tags: amazon-redshift, where-clause

In the below table, I want to write a SQL query to exclude a row when `col1=2` and `col2=1`. Only when both conditions are met, I want to drop that column. If `col1=2` but `col2<>1` then I want to keep that row.

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

I am trying this below snippet but it's not working:

```
select *
from table
where (col1<>2 and col2<>1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either:

```
WHERE NOT (col1 <> 2 AND col2 <> 1)
```

or

```
WHERE (col1 <> 2 OR col2 <> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `or` instead of `and`.